# Synchronize child component's input with grand parent. Many indirations

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have structure of components as below:

- main component

  - sub component

    - intermediate component

      - with the `<input>` component

Main component has `changeset` object with is populated from `ngrx` store. I want all `with the input components` be synchronized with `changeset` for performance reason and after `save button` `changeset` will be applied to `ngrx store`

Which angular feature should I use, to connect all `<input>` components to `changeset` in two-way data binding way.

Example with child -> parent

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bseiyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts

Example with child -> grand parent. And here to make this work I should duplicate event emitter which I think is not best way.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a13ztp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts

One solution which could be consider is reactive forms mentioned by @cogcak but still there is a problem with passing values at the bottom.

In my case, template doesn't look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="mainInput">
  <div formGroupName="childGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="childInput"
  </div>
</form>
```

But more or less like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="mainInput">
  <div formGroupName="childGroup">
    <child-that-has-input> type="text" formControlName="childInput"
  </div>
</form>
```

Or in reality even:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="mainInput">
  <div formGroupName="childGroup">
    <child-that-has-child-which-as-input type="text" formControlName="childInput"
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reactive form for the populated set of values coming from store at the init lifecycle of the input component.

```js
theReativeForm = new fb.group({
   changeSetOfValues: new fb.array([])
});
...
onInit() {
   const changeState$ = this.store.select(state => state.changeState);
   changeState$.subscribe(values => 
      values.forEach(value => 
         this.theReativeForm
           .get('changeSetOfValues')
           .push(this.fb.control(value)));
   );
}
```

then listen every change in the form to sync to the state in store,

```js
this.theReativeForm.get('changeSetOfValues').valueChanges(valuesFormArray =>
   yourUpdateStateReducerMethod(valuesFormArray.value);
);
```

Comment: @cogcak to clarify. I have two or more <inputs> with the same data source so they should refresh immediately while typing single character. So I don't want to push every character to the store. I want to keep changes outside the store until save button click.

Comment: then don't use valuechanges but keep values in reactive form, then let every changes will automatially binded to inputs. after all it's reactive right

Comment: the give an action to save button like `yourUpdateStateReducerMethod(valuesFormArray.value);`

Comment: ok I see. Does using reactive form allow me to have duplicated controls that points to same datasource?

Comment: Nevertheless I have problem with passing FormGroup from grand parent to child which  is <input>. Its more or less same problem as I faced with other approach

Comment: @userbb you can pass nested form values into child easly with @input() props. For child form values can go up to parent form with ng value accessors. Every component can have its own value (this.value), at the end you will have only one nested form contributed by children form values. its oop approach so to speak

Comment: Yes I already did that way. Just I feel that this not look good since I have many formGroup for only single input. I have my custom components that are wrappers for single i.e input etc. Thanks anyway